# Count how many days in a month there is a negative value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to know how many days (unique) in a month (col A) there is a negative value (col B)

I use `COUNTIF` but I'm receiving duplicates dates. In the spreadsheet I can have the same date more than once.

The col A is ordered and contains only dates in a certain month (only January dates or February, and so)

[image: A screenshot of my spreadsheet]

Comment: I tried this `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A30;A1:A30)>0;C2:C30))` but still buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can use `COUNT`, `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions to obtain the correct result. Try the following formula:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A10,B1:B10<0)))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Didn't know about FILTER neither UNIQUE functions. Thanks a lot, it's working like a charm.